# In Ruby on Rails, are '#encoding: utf-8' and 'config.encoding = "utf-8"' different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I can specify any ruby file to use specific encoding by add a comment line at its top:

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

But in Rails' `config/application.rb`, I found this:

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

Are they different? If I have set `config.encoding = "utf-8"`, still I need `#encoding: utf-8`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `config.encoding = "utf-8"` part in `config/application.rb` is related to how rails should interpret content.

`#encoding: utf-8` in a ruby file tells ruby that this file contains non-ascii characters.

These two cases are different. The first one (in `config/application.rb`) tells rails something, and has nothing at all to do with how ruby itself should interpret source files.

You can set the environment variable `RUBYOPT=-Ku` if you're lazy and want ruby to automatically set the default file encoding of `.rb` files to `utf-8`, but I'd rather recommend that you put your non-ascii bits in a translation file and reference that with `I18n.t`.

Comment: `how rails should interpret content`? Could you give an example?

Comment: This is related to what encoding rails should use when talking to the database, or retrieving data from a form, for instance.

Comment: Actually `#encoding: utf-8` tells ruby to *interpret* the source of the file as `utf-8`, even if it doesn't contain any non-ascii characters. ;)

Comment: What if the variable data itself has an accented character? (é). For example, in my Cucumber tests, I'm required to use accented characters to test against my repo. But Rails won't let me print these types of characters.

Comment: @Trip In that case, you'll need to have `#encoding: utf-8` in your cucumber tests. The ruby scripts themselves will still be able to handle unicode characters, such as accented characters.

Comment: This whole `#encoding: utf-8` business is only an issue when using ruby versions prior to 2.0.0. As of 2.0.0, ruby now defaults to interpret source files as utf-8.