# Error setting up gitlab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, gitlab

It was all good until I run this command.

`sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production`

My database.yml contains mysql2 as adapter. but stil it throws this error.

```
rake aborted!
Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.2/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.2/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/git/gitlab/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.2/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/backports-3.3.2/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:setup => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: did you install mysql2 gem?

Comment: Yes I did. Even I got the following output. Not sure if this is a problem

`Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.13
Parsing documentation for mysql2-0.3.13
unable to convert "\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/mysql2/mysql2.so, skipping
1 gem installed
`

Comment: ooh...it is encoding problem skipping gem install you see..so first encode it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699018/in-ruby-on-rails-are-encoding-utf-8-and-config-encoding-utf-8-differe thanks

Comment: that's for documentation. it shouldn't stop my using the command mentioned above