# Set UTF-8 as default for Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-1.9.3

I'm on Rails 4 and Ruby 1.9.3

I use "strange" characters very often, so I have to declare UTF-8 encoding at the top of all .rb files.

Is there any way to set UTF-8 as the default encoding for Ruby 1.9.3?

---

I tried all answers, but when running `rake db:seed` and creating an object whose attributes contain non `US-ASCII` valid characters, I still receive this error:

```
`block in trace_on': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: declaring default codepage at the beginning of each file as `utf-8` is need, when you use unicode char directly in the same .rb file. Which problem leaded to your question? 'UTF-8' cp is set in `ruby 1.9.x` by default. Do your have a string with non-utf codepage?

Comment: "'UTF-8' cp is set in ruby 1.9.x by default." this not true

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To change the source encoding (i.e. the encoding your actual written source code is in), you have to use the magic comment currently:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

It is not enough to either set the internal encoding (the encoding of the internal string representation after conversion) or the external encoding (the assumed encoding of read files). You actually have to set the magic encoding comment on top of files to set the source encoding.

In [ChiliProject](https://chiliproject.org) we have a [rake task](https://github.com/chiliproject/chiliproject/blob/c65779bbc1af3191c2336147b946977fcd67876e/lib/tasks/code.rake#L34-L62) which sets the correct encoding header in all files automatically before a release.

As for encoding defaults:

- Ruby 1.8 and below didn't knew the concept of string encodings at all. Strings were more or less byte arrays.
- Ruby 1.9: default string encoding is `US_ASCII` everywhere.
- Ruby 2.0 and above: default string encoding is `UTF-8`.

Thus, if you use Ruby 2.0, you could skip the encoding comment and correctly assume UTF-8 encoding everywhere by default.

Answer (score 13):

I think you would want one of the following, depending on the context.

```
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
```

This setting is made in the environment.rb file.

Comment: This only defined the internal encoding (the internal string representation after conversion) and external encoding (the default encoding of read files), but not the encoding of ruby source files. This can only be changed with magic comments on top of a source file.

Comment: I had to use this in a dockerized environment, where it defaulted to US-ASCII. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

> in Ruby 1.9 the default is ASCII
>
> in Ruby 2.0 the default is UTF-8.

change Ruby version

or

```
config.encoding = "utf-8" # application.rb
```

and
in your `database.yml`

```
development:
     adapter:  your_db
     host:     localhost
     encoding: utf8
```

Comment: in `database.yml` is just a recommendation and not necessarily

Answer (score 2):

In your **application.rb**

```
# Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

This is not the whole story as pointed out by Holger, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699018/in-ruby-on-rails-are-encoding-utf-8-and-config-encoding-utf-8-differe) for further explanation.

Comment: This only defined the internal encoding (the internal string representation after conversion) and external encoding (the default encoding of read files), but not the encoding of ruby source files. This can only be changed with magic comments on top of a source file.

Comment: That answer is the same as the answer someone else already said

Comment: how so? I feel my answer is not the best, but adds additional value that the other answers do not mention (the link and the discussion there)