# Can we add special characters inside comments of ruby files?

Tags: ruby, comments, special-characters

Need to add flow of my code in comments at the starting of class.
Found some symbols [here](https://www.alt-codes.net/arrow_alt_codes.php).

I did something like this inside my `.rb` file.

```
=begin
A
⬇
B
⬇
C
=end
```

It is not giving me any error but I need to be sure. Is it safe ?
Nothing should happen on deployment day :P

Comment: Yes, that is safe. `=begin` starts a multiline comment and there is nothing wrong with having those symbols in a comment.

Comment: Normally you just prefix lines with `#` and it's fine. The `=begin`, `=end` style is a lot more obscure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby permits defining [source file encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521371/set-utf-8-as-default-for-ruby-1-9-3#20523482).

If your characters are valid in that encoding, you should be fine.