# We're sorry, but something went wrong. ( Ruby On Rails Variable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, character

Layout;

```
  <title><%= @page_title %></title>
```

Controller;

```
 @page_title = "Serhan Yavçin"
```

Result;

## We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

## But

controller;

```
@page_title = "Serhan Yavin"
```

' Ç ' Turkish Charachter

Result; No Problem

Comment: Add `#encoding: utf-8` as a very first line of the file including your controller. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699018/in-ruby-on-rails-are-encoding-utf-8-and-config-encoding-utf-8-differe

Comment: config/application.rb  #encoding : utf-8  but not working :( ( I am sory i dont know english )

Comment: You need to add this to the controller, or any file which contains non ASCII character