# How to store Japanese kanji character in Oracle database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, activerecord, cjk

This Japanese character , which has four bytes, is saved as `????` in Oracle database whereas other Japanese characters are saved properly.

The configuration in `boot.rb` of my rails application contains:

```
ENV['NLS_LANG'] = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8'
```

and `sqldeveloper` of oracle db has

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CHARACTERSET    JA16SJISTILDE
```

The datatype of the column is `NVARCHAR2`.

Comment: When your column type is `NVARCHAR2` then `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` applies, not `NLS_CHARACTERSET`.

Comment: Thanks! NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET is AL16UTF16

Comment: What do you get from `select UNISTR('\D842\DFB7') from dual;`? What do you get when you select `DUMP(<column_name>, 1016) from ...`?

Comment: Can you do this without Ruby/Rails?

Comment: select DUMP(<column_name>, 1016) returns **Typ=1 Len=10 CharacterSet=AL16UTF16: 0,4e,0,61,0,6d,0,65,0,20**  and select UNISTR('\D842\DFB7') from dual returns ****

Comment: Ensure that your ruby-on-rail is entirely set to UTF-8, perhaps these help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908774/set-global-default-encoding-for-ruby-1-9 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699018/in-ruby-on-rails-are-encoding-utf-8-and-config-encoding-utf-8-differe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521371/set-utf-8-as-default-for-ruby-1-9-3

Answer (score 2):

Try `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`

Oracle Character set `UTF8` is actually [CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8) whereas `AL32UTF8` is commonly known **UTF-8**

If you stay in [Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) then `UTF8` and `AL32UTF8` are equal, however when you have characters above `U+FFFF` then they are different.

is `U+20BB7` which is Supplementary Ideographic Plane

Comment: Tried but didn't work. Any other encoding higher than this which will cover other characters in Supplementary Ideographic Plane?